# Ruby efficient each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a better way to write this? `markdown` is a StringIO

```
coverage_hash_arr = [
        {
          "Module": "Mobile",
          "name": "Sheila Chapman",
          "age": 21
        },
        {
          "Module": "Web",
          "name": "Hendricks Walton",
          "age": 40
        },
        {
          "Module": "Misc",
          "name": "Torres Mcdonald",
          "age": 39
        }
    ]

coverage_hash_arr.each do |the_hash|
    markdown << "------- Status on #{the_hash[:Module]} -------\n"
    the_hash.delete(:Module)
    the_hash.each {|key, value| markdown << "- #{key}: #{value} \n"} 
    markdown << "----------------------------------------------\n"
end
```

I tried this and it seems to work but I wonder if there's a better way (recursion)?

```
coverage_hash_arr.collect do |the_hash|
    the_hash.each do |key,value|
        key == :Module ? markdown << "--------- Status for #{value} ----------\n" : markdown << " - #{key}: #{value} \n"
      end
      markdown << "------------------------------------\n\n"
end
```

Comment: Hard to know when we do not know what `coverage_hash_arr` and `markdown` are. What is your input, what is the expected output? Btw are you really still on `ruby-on-rails-3`, are Rails version that is about 8 years old?

Comment: `markdown` is a StringIO (specified above) and `coverage_hash_arr` would be an array of hashes.

Comment: Remember in Ruby there's a huge difference between `"Module"` (String) and `:Module` (Symbol). These two are **not** equal. You get lucky here because `"Module": x` defines a Symbol key, the quotes are extraneous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

- use [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/IO.html#puts-method) instead of `<<` to avoid explicit newlines
- use [`center`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#center-method) to center the caption horizontally
- use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#map-method) to generate the attribute strings and utilize `puts`' behavior of printing array elements on separate lines
- use [`without`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-without) to get a hash without the `:Module` key
- use [`*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#2A-method) to repeat a string

Applied to your code:

```
markdown = StringIO.new

coverage_hash_arr.each do |hash|
  markdown.puts " Status on #{hash[:Module]} ".center(46, '-')
  markdown.puts hash.without(:Module).map { |k, v| "- #{k}: #{v}" }
  markdown.puts '-' * 46
  markdown.puts
end
```

Output via `puts markdown.string`:

```
-------------- Status on Mobile --------------
- name: Sheila Chapman
- age: 21
----------------------------------------------

--------------- Status on Web ----------------
- name: Hendricks Walton
- age: 40
----------------------------------------------

--------------- Status on Misc ---------------
- name: Torres Mcdonald
- age: 39
----------------------------------------------
```

Note that the above isn't proper Markdown syntax. You might want to change your output to something like this:

```
### Status on Mobile
- name: Sheila Chapman
- age: 21

### Status on Web
- name: Hendricks Walton
- age: 40

### Status on Misc
- name: Torres Mcdonald
- age: 39
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more streamlined version which has been adapted to be more idiomatic Ruby:

```rb
# Define your hashes with keys having consistent case, and omit extraneous
# surrounding quotes unless defining keys like "this-name" which are not
# valid without escaping.
coverage = [
  {
    module: "Mobile",
    name: "Sheila Chapman",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    module: "Web",
    name: "Hendricks Walton",
    age: 40
  },
  {
    module: "Misc",
    name: "Torres Mcdonald",
    age: 39
  }
]

# Iterate over each of these elements...
coverage.each do |entry|
  markdown << "------- Status on #{entry[:module]} -------\n"

  entry.each do |key, value|
    # Skip a particular key
    next if (key == :module)

    markdown << "- #{key}: #{value} \n"
  end

  markdown << "----------------------------------------------\n"
end
```

This can be adapted to have a list of keys to exclude, or the inverse, of having a list of keys to actually print.

There's really nothing wrong with your approach specifically. The major faux-pas committed is in using `delete` on the data, which mangles it, rendering it useless if you needed to print this again.

It's generally best to try and avoid tampering with the data you're iterating over *unless* the purpose of that code is clear in its intent to alter it.

Comment: Thanks! I like the the skipping of a particular key. Is there a way to do this without the nested `each` loop?

Comment: You can replace it with an `each`-like iterator, such as `map`, but if you want to print out those keys in a specific form you're sort of stuck with some variation on that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your input data has always the same key/value pairs and I would be more explicit to make it easier to read and to understand what the actual output is:

```
coverage_hash_arr.each do |hash|
  markdown << <<~STRING
    ------- Status on #{hash[:Module]} -------
    - name: #{hash[:name]}
    - age:  #{hash[:age]}
    ----------------------------------------------
  STRING
end
```